# How to create/implement an interceptor library correctly in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

This is my very firt post! I have implemented a small C++ program which uses the foo-implementation as a shared library. The shared library contains two functions: `get_number()` and `print_text()`.

The goal is that a interceptor library (shared library) changes the functions of the foo-library, such that

- `get_number()` should be replaced with a function that always returns 333.
- `print_text()` should be wrapped so that some text is printed before and after the original function is executed.

The source code is the following:

**foo.hpp**

```
#ifndef _FOO_HPP
#define _FOO_HPP

namespace foo {

    int get_number();

    void print_text();

}

#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.hpp"

#include <iostream>

namespace foo {

    int get_number()
    {
        return 13;
    }

    void print_text()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**interceptor.hpp**

```
#ifndef _INTERCEPTOR_HPP
#define _INTERCEPTOR_HPP

#include <iostream>

namespace interceptor {

    int get_number();

    void print_text();

}

#endif
```

**interceptor.cpp**

```
#include "interceptor.hpp"

namespace interceptor {

    int get_number()
    {
        return 333;
    }

    void print_text()
    {
        // Print here some text.
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
        // Print here some test.
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Number: " << foo::get_number() << "\n" << std::endl;
    foo::print_text();

    return 0;
}
```

Running the main-executable with and without the interceptor library could look like this:

```
$ ./main
Number: 13

Hello World!

$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/interceptor.so ./main
Number: 333

Hi before
Hello World!
Bye after
```

I'm a beginner in shared libraries and in interceptor libraries.

I hope that someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that. I have changed my post.

Comment: @RainerH. You made your question even broader. I did try to answer question (1), but now that isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

To link `main.o` with `foo.so` do e.g.:

```
g++ -o main main.o foo.so
```

If you then try to run

```
./main
```

you will get an error, because `foo.so` is not in the system library path where the dynamic linker looks for it. We can tell it to look in the current folder as well:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
Number: 13

Hello World!
```

Now with the `interceptor.so`:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. LD_PRELOAD=interceptor.so ./main
Number: 13

Hello World!
```

As you can see nothing changed. This is because your `interceptor.so` does not actually contain definitions for `foo::get_number` and `foo::print_text`. It contains definitions for `interceptor::get_number` and `interceptor::print_text`, but these are never called by `main`!

`interceptor.cpp` should implement the same functions as `foo.cpp`, so after replacing `namespace interceptor` with `namespace foo` everywhere and recompiling:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. LD_PRELOAD=interceptor.so ./main
Number: 333

Hello World!
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I have changed the namespace in the interceptor implementation and recompiled the source code. Now I understand how to compile and link that program (previously I have tried out different compiling and linking instructions). I have another question: how to wrap the foo::print_text() function in interceptor such that some text is printed before and after the original function is executed?